# Retrieving data from database and printing value in shell scripting

Tags: shell

In shell scripting I am retrieving data from database and trying to print it, but it does not print as I am trying to do it.

My code is:

```
 mysql -uroot -proot -Dproject_ivr_db -rN --execute "SELECT Regular FROM 
 Fee_MSc WHERE Fee_Type='Total:'" | while read value

 x=1

 do
       echo "V,FeeRegular_$y=$value"
       let "y+=1"
 done

 echo "V,fee_msc_regular="for students on regular basis admission fee 
 including other charges is $FeeRegular_1 and semester fee is $FeeRegular_2""
```

Output is:

```
 V,FeeRegular_1=12590
 V,FeeRegular_2=12850

 V,fee_msc_regular=for students on regular basis admission fee including other
 charges is and semester fee is
```

It does not print the values of `$FeeRegular_1` and `$FeeRegular_2` in the string output.

How can I get the values of these variables in the output string?

Comment: Which shell? Why are you logging into the DB as root to run a query? And what kind of password is that?

Comment: root is the password as well as root name i have set for mysql database and there is nothing wrong as for as the database is concerned problem is with the echo statement

Comment: and i am using asterisk dial plan where i have to finally use these values and shell is writing in test3.sh file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)-like shell, the variables that you are looking to create do not exist when the `while`-loop exists. This is because you are piping the results and creating a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SUBSHELL) with a new environment, which is not shared with the parent shell.

You can restructure your loop to be a `for`-loop using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). Rather than attempting to append a number to the end of a variable name, use an [array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for value in $(mysql -u{$db_user} -p${db_pass} -D${db_name} -rN --execute "
    SELECT Regular FROM Fee_MSc WHERE Fee_Type='Total:' ")
do
    FeeRegular[$i]=${value}
    echo "FeeRegular[$i]=${FeeRegular[$i]}"
    let "i+=1"
done
echo "Found ${#FeeRegular[@]} fees..."
echo "For students on regular basis admission fee including other charges is
${FeeRegular[1]} and semester fee is ${FeeRegular[2]}."
```

I also recommend not using the root account for querying the database, increasing the strength of your passwords and *not publishing them*.

Now... are you sure the results you are looking for are in rows 1 and 2? You've specified no `order by` clause in your query. But that's a separate issue.